# Using JQueryUI accordion navigation:true w/base tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, navigation, accordion, radix

I'm putting this here for anyone who may possibly have this problem with JQueryUI accordion widget. The markup used is a slight variation of the default markup in their demo:

```
<div class='my-list'>
  <h3><a href='#item-one'>Some item</a></h3>
  <div class='my-list-text' id='item-one'>Some long bit of text</div>
  <h3><a href='#item-two'>Some item</a></h3>
  <div class='my-list-text' id='item-two'>Some other long bit of text</div>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Note the href attributes in the `<h3>` elements explicitly link to the `<div>`s next to them. The accordion is called as follows:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
  $('.my-list').accordion({
    navigation:true,
    autoHeight:false,
    collapsible:true
  });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

If you set a base href to something other than the current page using a `<base>` tag in the `<head>` element, you must explicitly point the hrefs inside the `<h3>`s to the current page in order for incoming links w/hashes to correctly toggle the accordion, like so:

```
<div class='my-list'>
  <h3><a href='thispage.html#item-one'>Some item</a></h3>
  <div class='my-list-text' id='item-one'>Some long bit of text</div>
  <h3><a href='thispage.html#item-two'>Some item</a></h3>
  <div class='my-list-text' id='item-two'>Some other long bit of text</div>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

So if for some reason you use the `<base>` element on a page w/JQueryUI accordion and navigation isn't working properly, try the above!

Comment: @Shikiryu at first, I don't think it's usefull to comment on a post which is almost 2 years old. And at second, it's something that is OK on stackexchange: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @WouterJ First, it's always good to comment a downvote and/or a close vote. Seems fair to justify myself. Second, the link you gave is about someone **asking a question** and **answering it**. Thing he didn't do at all. As he says : *I'm putting this here for anyone who may possibly have this problem with JQueryUI accordion widget.*

Comment: @Shikiryu *"So (...) if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later"*

Comment: @WouterJ Then, he did it badly. He should have ask up there and answer down there and accept his own answer. That way, this question wouldn't have come up in **unanswered**. See the example in your given link.

Comment: @WouterJ Even though the comment _Open a blog, buddy._ is completely unnecessary IMO, I agree with Shikiryu: This is an answer posted as a question, not a question AND an answer.

Comment: @A.Rodas Fair enough. Thought it was funny to say that. As you can see, my comment was edited ; that edit was that sentence added... Can't edit it now.

Comment: Found this on Google while looking for examples on how to set up navigation in Accordions so it's not all that useless.